# WSO2 - Add user using through RemoteUserStoreManagerService API

Tags: c#, asp.net, wso2

I'm trying to create WSO2 users using RemoteUserStoreManagerService in my applicaition. A user is created but I'm getting an exception "The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error."

Looking through WSO2 Management Console I see that user is created and in Log there are errors:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-01 09:08:36,813]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler} -  Illegal access attempt at [2018-02-01 09:08:36,0813] from IP address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 while trying to authenticate access to service RemoteUserStoreManagerService 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-01 09:08:36,814] ERROR {AUDIT_LOG} -  Illegal access attempt at [2018-02-01 09:08:36,0813] from IP address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 while trying to authenticate access to service RemoteUserStoreManagerService 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-01 09:08:36,826] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AbstractAuthenticator} -  Invalid remote address detected. 
org.wso2.carbon.core.common.AuthenticationException: Authentication Failed : Invalid remote address passed - 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.validateRemoteAddress(AuthenticationUtil.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.getRemoteAddress(AuthenticationUtil.java:156)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AbstractAuthenticator.getRemoteAddress(AbstractAuthenticator.java:304)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:136)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.isAuthenticated(AuthenticationHandler.java:171)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AuthenticationHandler.java:96)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.module.handler.AuthenticationHandler.invoke(AuthenticationHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:167)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-01 09:08:36,836]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2018-02-01 09:08:36,836+0100] 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-01 09:08:36,837]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} -  'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2018-02-01 09:08:36,836+0100] 
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-01 09:08:36,918]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} -  Initiator : admin@carbon.super | Action : Add User | Target : usertest1 | Data : { Roles :Administrator, } | Result : Success
```

Here is my code:

```
        RemoteUserStoreManagerServicePortTypeClient wso2Svc = new RemoteUserStoreManagerServicePortTypeClient("RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint");
        try
        {
            wso2Svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "admin";
            wso2Svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "mypassword";
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
              delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate,
                       X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
              { return true; };

            string[] roles = { "Administrator" };
            RemoteUserStoreManagerService.ClaimValue[] claims = { new RemoteUserStoreManagerService.ClaimValue() { claimURI = "http://wso2.org/claims/lastname", value = "test" } };

            wso2Svc.addUser("usertest1", "usertest1", roles, claims, "default", false);
            wso2Svc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            wso2Svc.Abort();
            throw ex;
        }
```

Any idea why I am getting this errors "Illegal access attempt" and "Invalid remote address detected" before the user is successfully created?

Comment: This is because your requesting address is not a valid one. Can you set that before you do the request

Comment: Address in my web.config file is generated automatically when I added service reference with address "https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl". 
Here is im config: `<endpoint address="https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService.RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint/"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceSoap11Binding"               contract="RemoteUserStoreManagerService.RemoteUserStoreManagerServicePortType" name="RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint"/>`

Comment: And in <basicHttpBinding> I have a section: `<binding name="RemoteUserStoreManagerServiceSoap11Binding">            
                  <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                  </security>
                </binding>`

Comment: I mean not the destination. but the source address

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I'm not sure what should I set before I do the request and how to make my source address valid. How can I know why is the address invalid? I appreciate your help.